# AWS Parameter Store Values Not Recognized in Spring Boot Application with @ConfigurationProperties

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, aws-parameter-store

I have a following class in one of the spring boot application.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "authorizepartner")
@Component
@Data
public class EnabledClientNameForAuthorize {
  private List<String> enabledClientName;
}
```

in `application.properties` file I have given `authorizepartner.enabledclientname=ABC`

We are using the AWS Parameter store to override the properties configured in this file.

In the parameter store I have tried with following configuration but its seems not getting considered.

```
"authorizepartner.enabledClientName":"ABC,XYZ"
"authorizepartner.enabledclientname":"ABC,XYZ"
```

Things are working fine if I use @Value such as below and override it in the AWS parameter store.

```
@Value("${valid.productIds}")
private Set<String> validProductIds;
```

To override `valid.productIds` given in `application.properties` we are simply putting below in parameter store and its working fine.

```
"valid.productIds": "PQR,ASDF"
```